# Trying to Migrate to Iron-Router from Router

Tags: iron-router

I am trying to migrate from router to iron-router but having a problem with my entire page not rendering correctly. The only template that is rendering is what is produced from the "> yield". Any of the other code in my HTML, file is not rendered.

I would like everything on the page to remain static. But I want the template in yield to change based on the url. What am I missing in the configuration to make it behave that way?

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>carpool</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>  
  <div id="wrap">
    {{> page}}
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      {{> header}}      
    </div>   
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span10">
        <template name="mainContent">
          {{> yield}}
        </template>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        {{#if currentUser}}
        {{> leaderboard}}
        {{/if}}
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="push"></div>
   </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      {{> footer}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="page">
  {{#if showAddEventDialogue}}
    {{> addEvent}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showConfigLoginService}}
    {{> configureLoginService}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showCalendarEventDetailsDialogue}}
    {{> calendarEventDetailsDialogue}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
/* Only execute if this is the client */
if (Meteor.isClient) {

// Client subscriptions
Meteor.subscribe('allCarpoolEvents');
Meteor.subscribe('allCarpoolDebts');
Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');

// Do not render the <body>
Router.configure({
  autoRender: true
});

// Define Routes
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('calendar', {
    path:'/calendar*',
    template: 'mainContent',
    layoutTemplate: 'calendar'
  });
  this.route('list', {
    path:'/list*',
    template: 'mainContent',
    layoutTemplate: 'list'
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest key I was missing is that iron-router replaces the `<body>` of your document. Moving my template out of the `<body>` of the HTML document makes it work. Here is the corrected code:

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>carpool</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

</body>

<template name="mainContent">
  <div id="wrap">
    {{> page}}
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
      {{> header}}      
    </div>   
    <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span10">
        {{> yield}}
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        {{#if currentUser}}
              {{> leaderboard}}
        {{/if}}
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div id="push"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    {{> footer}}
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<template name="page">
  {{#if showAddEventDialogue}}
    {{> addEvent}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showConfigLoginService}}
    {{> configureLoginService}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if showCalendarEventDetailsDialogue}}
    {{> calendarEventDetailsDialogue}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
/* Only execute if this is the client */
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  // Client subscriptions
  Meteor.subscribe('allCarpoolEvents');
  Meteor.subscribe('allCarpoolDebts');
  Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');


  Router.configure({
    autoRender: true
  });

  // Define Routes
  Router.map(function () {

    this.route('calendar', {
      path:'/',
      template: 'calendar',
      layoutTemplate: 'mainContent'
    });

    this.route('calendar', {
      path:'/calendar*',
      template: 'calendar',
      layoutTemplate: 'mainContent'
    });

    this.route('list', {
      path:'/list*',
      template: 'list',
      layoutTemplate: 'mainContent'
    });
  });
}
```